# DOJO Filtering select RegExp query

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
filteringSelect.query = {id: "12|13"};
```

or

```
filteringSelect.query = {id: new RegExp("12|13")};
```

Is it possible?

I am using ItemFileReadStore as a store for that FilteringSelect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Fuzzy Matches on dijit.form.ComboBox / dijit.form.FilteringSelect Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200142/fuzzy-matches-on-dijit-form-combobox-dijit-form-filteringselect-subclass) if you want to go the extra mile. This is however for filtering user-input.

For filtering away entries before opening/entering anything in the filteringSelect, continue what youre doing allready. A simple string will not accept the OR operator though, use `RegExp`.

[ItemFileReadStore docs on query](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#query-syntax)

```
var store = new ItemFileReadStore( {
    query: {
       id: new RegExp("/^(12|13)$/")
    }
} );
```

As a starting point, ALL items are present in the store, the way to make use of the queryengine is through `fetch`

```
store.fetch({
        query: { 
          // yes, you can set the query property directly 
          // in the store and leave out this parameter
            id: new RegExp("^(1|12)$")
        },
        onComplete: function(items) {
            dojo.forEach(items, function(item) {
                console.log(store.getValue(item, 'name'))
            });
        }

    })
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LuUbT/ for example usage

Comment: Thank you but i tried it already and nothing works! i am using json as a store (not url on server )

Comment: then youre doing it wrong :) see my edited answer or the fiddle linked above here

Comment: Should it be `new RegExp("/^(12|13)$/")` or `new RegExp("^(12|13)$")`? (with slashes or without)