# How to filter/query a FilteringSelect in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, filtering

I'm trying to change the query of a filtering select's data store, such that the dropdown only displays the values that were queried with a query such as this (note that I can't even get it to work with a non-regex query):

```
var query = {
    id: new RegExp("^(1|12)$")
};
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pohpgaLL/70/).

Note that I do not want to `fetch` the result set using

```
dropdown.store.fetch({query: query, onComplete: function(results) {} });
```

I want the results to filter **in the dropdown**.

Despite viewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110959/dojo-filtering-select-regexp-query) and several other related questions, I haven't been able to get a solution that works for a FilteringSelect as I intend. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does using the RegExp like this: `RegExp(/^(1|12)$/)` work?

Comment: @Richard [Both are identical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description), but as I said, I can't get it to work with *any* query, whether regex or not.

Comment: @Richard Also, I couldn't use that anyway, because in the end I need a dynamic regex. The example I provided above is simplified slightly.

Comment: To get your fiddle to actually query correctly, I've updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pohpgaLL/71/. But to get the results of what you're trying to do, you'll need to extend filtering select and override the `_openResultList` function inside the FilteringSelect. Either that or you can look into the dojo mixins that FilteringSelect is built from and build your own version of FilteringSelect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what I was trying to do, you have to **query the FilteringSelect**, not the store.

```
dropdown.query.id = /^(1|12)$/;
```

But even better, this works for all queries, not just regex, since the function can be anything:

```
dropdown.query.id = {
   test: function (id) {
          return [1, 12].indexOf(id) > -1;
   }
};
```

Note: This `query` property is inherited from `dijit/form/_SearchMixin`. See the properties of [`FilteringSelect`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect).

Comment: You should've been able to simply set the query on the filtering select, a la `dropdown.set("query", function(o) { return true-under-some-condition; })`. See http://jsfiddle.net/mmaxwell/kugGH/2/

Comment: @inanutshellus That's good if there's only a single condition, but if you want to conditionally filter on multiple properties, maybe using the results of other FilteringSelects, then it's easier to have a separate filter for each property and set them separately like I did with `dropdown.query.property = function (p) {...};`. But, you're right. I could have set the property to the function without using `test`. Thanks.